# scatter or are scattered

Tags: past-participles

> Historical enclaves **are scattered** throughout the island.
>
> Historical enclaves **scatter** throughout the island.

I prefer no. 1 as "scatter" means "make sth drop or throw". I think no-one can make enclaves drop or throw. I want to know which is better to use in the sentence,  **scatter** or **are scattered.**

Comment: I@Max If then, what is the answer, scatter or are scattered? I assume enclaves cannot go in various directions.

Answer (score 1):

When something is **scattered throughout** a place, that which is scattered is *sparse*.

If settlements are scattered throughout the land, the land is sparsely settled, not *densely* settled.

If rosebushes are scattered throughout the garden, a rosebush may be found here and there in the garden; a section of the garden has not been devoted to roses.

If a certain species of tree is scattered throughout the island, the tree can be found here and there on the entire island. The trees are not all clustered at the north end of the island, say, or found only along the beaches. The trees could be said to "dot" the island, but the "dots" would be few and far between.

The verb **scatter** can be intransitive or transitive. and when used as a predicate adjective it means "to be in a state resembling the state of something which has been scattered."

INTRANSITIVE
When a crowd of people scatters, the crowd disperses, with the individuals going away in all directions, more or less randomly.

PASSIVE FORMED FROM THE TRANSITIVE
When seeds are scattered by the farmer, they are thrown out in a manner that causes them to fall randomly upon the soil; they are not placed neatly in individual holes that have been arranged in rows or set a fixed distance apart.

PREDICATE ADJECTIVE
Settlements are scattered throughout the region.